# Create All Possible Subsets from an Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

i want to Create All Possible Combintations for 2D Array in PHP

here is my Array

```
$skus = [
    ["A","B","C"],
    ["L","M","N"],
    ["","B","C"]
];
```

the possible Solution i want are as follows

```
$skus = [
    ["A"],
    ["B"],
    ["C"],
    ["L"],
    ["M"],
    .
    .
    .
    ["A","L"],
    ["A","M"],
    ["A","N"],
    .
    .
    .
    ["A","L","X"]
];
```

I have tried the one but it's giving only Three Combination Possibilities

```
public function possibleCombinations($arrays, $i = 0) {
    if (!isset($arrays[$i])) {
        return array();
    }
    if ($i == count($arrays) - 1) {
        return $arrays[$i];
    }

    // get combinations from subsequent arrays
    $tmp = $this->possibleCombinations($arrays, $i + 1);

    $result = array();

    // concat each array from tmp with each element from $arrays[$i]
    foreach ($arrays[$i] as $v) {
        foreach ($tmp as $t) {
            $skusComb = is_array($t) ?
                array_merge(array($v), $t) :
                array($v, $t);
            $result[]["sku_set"] = implode(",", $skusComb);
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Thank You

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Please post your php code.

Comment: please see again